# How to launch android application on real device

Tags: java, android, appium

android device is sony xperia Z ,version 4.3.

I want to automate native calculator app.

**The Code :**

```
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.*;

    public class Calculator {

     WebDriver driver;

     @BeforeClass
     public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{

          //Set up desired capabilities and pass the Android app-activity and app-package to Appium
          DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
         capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
         capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.3");
         capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Windows");
         capabilities.setCapability("device","");
         capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "com.android.calculator2"); // This is package name of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
         capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"); // This is Launcher activity of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
            //Create RemoteWebDriver instance and connect to the Appium server.
            //It will launch the Calculator App in Android Device using the configurations specified in Desired Capabilities
         driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

     }
     @Test
     public void testCal(){
         //locate the Text on the calculator by using By.name()
         WebElement two=driver.findElement(By.name("2"));
         two.click();
         WebElement plus=driver.findElement(By.name("+"));
         plus.click();
         WebElement four=driver.findElement(By.name("4"));
         four.click();
         WebElement equalTo=driver.findElement(By.name("="));
         equalTo.click();
         //locate the edit box of the calculator by using By.tagName()
         WebElement results=driver.findElement(By.tagName("EditText"));
                //Check the calculated value on the edit box
                assert results.getText().equals("6"):"Actual value is : "+results.getText()+" did not match with expected value: 6";
      }

     @AfterClass
     public void teardown(){
         //close the app
         driver.quit();
     } 
     }
```

**The Steps:**

**1.** connected device with system and check with command adb devices - it shows my device is connected.

**2.** started appium by using command : `appium &`  - server is started successfully.

**3.** Execute the code:

I get this **Error**:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Parameter 'appPackage' is required for launching application) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9.50 seconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: 'Admin-PC', ip: '192.168.1.13', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
    at ExecuteTest.initialize(ExecuteTest.java:30)
    at ExecuteTest.main(ExecuteTest.java:16)
```

Comment: Where is your main activity ,, and your Manifest file ?

Comment: Is your application running on avd ???

Comment: As user2385504 asked is it running on a emulator does it crash on your device or just not start at all on your device?

Comment: i have changed the package name and app activity as per my application
  capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "com.sonymobile.smallapps.calc"); // This is package name of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
     capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", "com.sonymobile.smallapps.calc.TestActivity"); // This is Launcher activity of your app (you can get it from apk info app)

Comment: but still shows same error.. i am not running it on emulator . i am executing the application on my device .it is not started

Comment: have you **ON** the developers mode in  your phone?

Comment: Yes, and my device is connected successfully .actually, my reputation score are not 10 thats why i can's paste the console image so you you guys able to see complete error.

Comment: in which **IDE** are you developing your app? have you faced such problem before OR is it your first time running the app in your phone?

Comment: I was downloaded the ADT bundle in which i got the eclipse.it is my first time

Answer (score 1):

Please match your code with the following list of capabilities and use Appium 1.0:

```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","sony xperia Z");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
   capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
   driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

or if package and activity details are like below use the same

```
       capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.sonymobile.smallapps.calc"); 
 capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.sonymobile.smallapps.calc.TestActivity");
```

Comment: Please change 'app-package' to 'appPackage' and 'app-activity' to 'appActivity' to make this work.