# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: spawn ENOENT)

Tags: java, android, appium

```
package android.appium;


import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;



public class SimpleTestCalc {

    WebDriver driver;
  @BeforeTest
  public void setup () throws MalformedURLException {
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","ZX1PC2JJPM");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.calculator");
        URL url1=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        driver=new RemoteWebDriver(url1,capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void sum() {
      driver.findElement(By.name("2")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("5")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("+")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("5")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("=")).click();
        String result=driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).getText();
        System.out.print("Sum of values is"+result);

  }

  @AfterTest
  public void reset() {
        driver.quit();
  }

}
```

Output:

[TestNG] Running:

> C:\Users\vgaarlap.ORADEV\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1070157593\testng-customsuite.xml
>
> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could
>   not be created. (Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: spawn
>   ENOENT) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 149 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
>   System info: host: 'VGAARLAP-LAP', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_31' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

Comment: Take a look at this stackoverflow [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672428/how-to-launch-android-application-on-real-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add system32 location in your environment path variable.

```
%SystemRoot%system32
```

For further details see the below link:

https://discuss.appium.io/t/original-error-java-version-failed-error-spawn-enoent/3125